# How do I find singularities and residue?

Tags: complex-analysis

Given is $f(z)=\sin(\exp(\frac{1}{z}))$. How do I find singularities and residue?

I know that singularity for my function is $z_0=0$. But how do I find residue?

Answer (score 3):

The residue of $f$ at $0$ is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert z\rvert = r} f(z)\,dz,\tag{1}$$

where since $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ the radius $r$ can be chosen arbitrarily. (Generally, it must be chosen small enough that the circle doesn't enclose nor pass through any other singularity.)

Making the substitution $w = 1/z$ in $(1)$ yields - note that the substitution leads to a negatively oriented circle; we then use the minus sign of the derivative to change the orientation -

$$\operatorname{Res} (f;0) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\lvert w\rvert = R} \frac{\sin (\exp w)}{w^2}\,dw$$

(where $R = 1/r$), which is easy to evaluate if one remembers the integral formula for derivatives.

Comment: $Z=0$ is a singularity but it is a pole?

Comment: No, it's an essential singularity.

Comment: But what is my 'r'?

Comment: @Majica Choose what you like. $r = 1$, or $r = 1/10$, it doesn't matter. Or don't choose at all and let it be an abstract value. The integrals don't depend on the radius of the respective circle.

Comment: But we have R and that is 1/r it depends.

Comment: Not really @Majica. By Cauchy's integral theorem, the integral over $\lvert z\rvert = r$ is equal to the integral $\lvert z\rvert = s$ for all $r,s > 0$. It doesn't matter which radius one chooses. And you don't evaluate the last integral by parametrising the circle, but by appealing to the integral formula (or the residue theorem), so there is no need to choose a radius.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the way forward presented by Daniel, we can expand the function $f(z)$ in a Laurent series.  Proceeding we write

$$\begin{align}
f(z)&=\sin\left(e^{1/z}\right)\\\\
&=\sin\left(1+\frac1z+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1z+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\right)^{2n+1}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}+\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}\right)\,\frac1z+O\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)\\\\
\end{align}$$

The residue is, therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}=\cos(1)$.

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.